# A simply question on open set.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual topology. We suppose that $A, B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ are open, and suppose we have shown that $$A=B\cap C,$$
where $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$

> **Question.** Can I conclude that $C$ is open?

Thansks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Suppose that $A=B\neq\mathbb R^n$. Take $p\in\mathbb R^n\setminus A$ and let $C=A\cup\{p\}$. Then $C$ is *not* open, but $A=B\cap C$.

Answer (score 0):

No, consider $A = B = (a,b)$ and $C = [a,b]$ for $n =1$. You can find counterexamples for $n \geq 2$ similarly (use open and closed balls).